# Bootstrap Navbar not collapsing in mobiles

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some issues with how a website displays on mobile devices and tablets.

The website in question is [luso liquors](http://lusoliquors.com.au/)

When you view the website on a desktop and you resize the window, its works perfectly but when you load it directly on a mobile device, it just loads the desktop version.

I have this line on my head

There is also the issue of the links that activate the dropdown not working in the mobile version, even though the modal and my custom jquery is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss the title close tag in your html

```
   <title>Welcome to Lusoliquors - Luso Liquors</title
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

it should be

```
   <title>Welcome to Lusoliquors - Luso Liquors</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

close the title tag.